# jenkins agent on mac directory not accessible

Tags: macos, jenkins, unix, launchctl, jenkins-agent

I am trying to start jenkins agent on Mac Mini with following `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.jenkins.ci.plist`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.jenkins.ci</string>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>jenkins</string>
        <key>SessionCreate</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
            <string>-Djava.awt.headless=true</string>
            <string>-jar</string>
            <string>/Users/jenkins/agent.jar</string>
            <string>-jnlpUrl</string>
            <string>http://jenkins2.domain.net:8080/computer/jenkins-mac/slave-agent.jnlp</string>
            <string>-secret</string>
            <string>23erft6yhujnhyujnbftyujbvcdrtyhbvcxswedaw</string>
            <string>-workDir</string>
            <string>"/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/"</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/jenkins/error.log</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/jenkins/stdout.log</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Then
`sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.jenkins.ci.plist`

But in the `/Users/jenkins/error.log`

I see

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The specified working directory should be fully accessible to the remoting executable (RWX): "/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/"
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager.verifyDirectory(WorkDirManager.java:249)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager.initializeWorkDir(WorkDirManager.java:202)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:300)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:283)
```

I have opened up `/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/` with `777` still getting this error.

```
jenkins2-slave3:~ jenkins$ ls -ld /Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/
drwxrwxrwx  5 jenkins  jenkins  160 Nov 13  2018 /Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/
jenkins2-slave3:~ jenkins$ ls -ld /Users/jenkins/
drwxr-xr-x+ 44 jenkins  staff  1408 Jun  5 10:12 /Users/jenkins/
```

If I run following on mac as `jenkins` user, it works

`/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /Users/jenkins/agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins2.domain.net:8080/computer/jenkins-mac/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 23erft6yhujnhyujnbftyujbvcdrtyhbvcxswedaw -workDir "/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/"`

Anyone knows what's wrong here ?

System Software Overview:

```
  System Version: macOS 10.14.4 (18E226)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 18.5.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode: Normal
  Computer Name: jenkins-slave
  User Name: jenkins (jenkins)
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled
  Time since boot: 7 days 23:11
```

Comment: have you looked into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794811/jenkins-does-not-start-on-macos-10-12-sierra... Mostly it looks like a permission issue, just do a chown.

Comment: I tried whatever solution mentioned on this, but didn't fix the issue I am having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason it works for "jenkins" user is because Jenkins creates a Application account with `jenkins` user which has permissions to run/access Jenkins(and its folders- in your case `-workDir "/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/"`). That is why `jenkins` can run the command but when you try to run it with sudo it fails.

> Why does it fail with sudo ?

That's mainly because  there is directory higher in the tree where you do not have execute permission, so even with 777, you will still not be able to run it.

Instead do a `chown` or `usermod` on the directory to the user that you wish to get access

```
sudo usermod -a -G rohit git
```

for more information https://askubuntu.com/questions/812513/permission-denied-in-777-folder

Comment: I can open up `/Users/jenkins/` with `777`, but I don't think that's appropriate here. If `jenkins` slave starting as jenkins user, then why its not able to access `/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/` ?

Comment: You shouldn't give full access to any folder/directory instead give permission to own the directory which the above answer does... As for the slave issue have you confirmed that you are using the same user ?? there is also an option `"Run as user who Triggered build"` for a  more detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453529/jenkins-slave-runs-as-user

Comment: I am getting mentioned error when jenkins slave start on Mac Mini. Not at the time of build. Also in `com.jenkins.ci.plist` file I am specifying `UserName` with which user to start the slave process.

Comment: Have you tried login into the server with this "`UserName`" and tried running the command directly ?? Most probably the user will not have access.

Comment: Yes I have mentioned this into my original post above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was the quotes for the directory:

```
<string>"/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/"</string>
```

Just remove them and it will work:

```
<string>/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/</string>
```